# Best CMS to pick for a large number of pages

Tags: cms

Good day,

I am orientating myself on a CMS that would be suitable for a website with a large number of pages.

We are talking about 15000+ pages.
The website that is to be realized has to offer many different information pages about car engine parts and specific ratings. So we have Engine A that has revision A, B, C etc etc. And each should have a page. Then for each revision there are common problems or things one need to know.

Just a tad of background information.

Important is not that a large community should work on it with user rights. But what is important that pages should be insertable by an API.

This is not really a must have. As long as it would be possible to add this feature myself.

Important that the system would be opensource or opensource with paid support. Also fine. But self hosted and PHP MySQL.

The only system so far I could find would be Typo3 CMS. But I am not quite convinced yet.
Since it is important that the system should have a way implemented that it is easy to manage each of those 15000+ pages by hand.

If you want to add something. No problem simply lookup the page and change it through the CMS.
You want to type everything by hand? No problem through the CMS you should be able to do it.
Want to have a system with a database to add all pages or extra pages. No problem. The API or self build / added API can do that.

That's what I want.

But I am not quite sure which system would be suitable. Since I worked mainly with websites up to 300 pages.

Now 15000+ is a challenge to me.
The website already exists and has good SEO ratings. But should be imported to a new CMS that's up to date.